# How can I specify the mainClass in the manifest with minijar-maven-plugin?

Tags: java, maven-2, jar, manifest

I'm using the minijar-maven-plugin to reduce the size of my jar-with-dependencies jar but I need to specify a mainClass like I can do easily with the maven assembly plugin. How can i specify the mainClass in the manifest while still using the minijar plugin?

My minijar configuration is the default:

```
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>minijar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>ueberjar</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <includeArtifact>true</includeArtifact>
                    <stripUnusedClasses>false</stripUnusedClasses>
                    <includeDependencies>
                        <param>org.vafer:dependency</param>
                    </includeDependencies>
                    <includeDependenciesInRelocation>
                        <param>org.vafer:dependency</param>
                    </includeDependenciesInRelocation>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

I can specify the main class in a maven assembly plugin using:

```
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <mainClass>com.chheng.Main</mainClass>
                </manifest>
            </archive>
            <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try the maven shade plugin. It deals better with metadata and also take care of the dependency inlining.

I've deprecated the minijar plugin and instead [added support](http://github.com/tcurdt/maven-plugins/commit/5ac23b358b15ed315c871a3b8cb3301a86802a8d) for the same optimizatiosn to the maven shade plugin.

Watch/vote for [this issue](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MSHADE-84) to get it applied.

Answer (score 0):

This has been requested - see this [executable uberjar](http://markmail.org/message/o4fyxljcexju5xgh) thread and [MOJO-852](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MOJO-852) - but is still not supported. And given that this issue is open for more than 3 years now, I would not expect a fast resolution (unless you submit a patch).

---

I don't know the minijar plugin very well, I never used it actually... but what happens if you configure the jar plugin to generate a manifest with the main-class entry for the main jar?

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <archive>
      <manifest>
        <!--addClasspath>true</addClasspath-->
        <mainClass>my.main.Class</mainClass>
        </manifest>
    </archive>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks for linking the mojo ticket. I created a reward for anyone who can submit a patch for it. http://nextsprocket.com/tasks/mojo-852-add-manifest-file-in-minijar-ueberjar